# Rails 4: Selecting records between current date and given specific date/number of days in past

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a **Customer table** in my Rail app. In the customer table one field is **customer_expiry_date**.

I want to add a filter in my application, that means customers, who all are expires within the following criteria:

1. Expire within one(1) day.
2. Expire within seven(7) days.
3. Expire within one(1) month.

How should I write my query using where clause to achieve this ?

My current query is like:

```
@customers = Customer.where.not(customer_expiry_date: nil)
```

How to select customers into three collection based on my requirement ?

```
@customers_exp_1day = ?
@customers_exp_1week = ?
@customers_exp_1month = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a scope in your model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # your code
  scope :expired_in, -> (from_now) {
    where.not(customer_expiry_date: nil).where('customers."customer_expiry_date" >= ? AND customers."customer_expiry_date" <= ?', Time.now, Time.now + from_now)
  }
end
```

Then use it:

```
@customers_exp_1day = Customer.expired_in(1.day)
@customers_exp_1week = Customer.expired_in(1.week)
@customers_exp_1month = Customer.expired_in(1.month)
```

Now it will work with the latest update.

Comment: Than you but I got an error, I dont know how that happened :)

Comment: (byebug) @customers_exp_1day
  Customer Load (49.2ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"  WHERE ("customers"."customer_expiry_date" IS NOT NULL) AND (customer_expiry_date >= '2016-02-03 09:54:58.857223' AND customer_expiry_date <= '2016-02-04 09:54:58.857242')
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "customer_expiry_date" does not exist
LINE 1: ...  WHERE ("customers"."customer_expiry_date" IS NOT NULL) AND (customer_expiry_date...

Comment: column name is same "customer_expiry_date" in my table.

Comment: Dude, thanks with a little change your scope worked for me

Comment: scope :expired_in, -> (from_now) {
    where.not(customer_expiry_date: nil).where('customers."customer_expiry_date" >= ? AND customers."customer_expiry_date" <= ?', Time.now, Time.now + from_now)
  }

Answer (score 1):

```
@customers_exp_1day = Customer.where("customer_expiry_date <= ?",
    Date.tomorrow)
@customers_exp_1week = Customer.where("customer_expiry_date <= ?",
    Date.today + 1.week)
@customers_exp_1month = Customer.where("customer_expiry_date <= ?", 
    Date.today + 1.month)
```

You had "Customers" in your question and I used "Customer" here, assuming that your model name is actually singular.

Comment: @J Plato : yes its singular, but @customers just given as collection name as it may contain more than one customer.

Comment: @PraveenGeorge, I was talking about the class name in your "where" query.  You have "Customers.where..."  (should be "Customer.where")

Comment: @J Plato : oh sorry dude ;) Anyway thanks for the answer :) Let me try it, once ok, I will approve it, cheers :)

Comment: @J Plato : The following error occurs :(
irb(main):005:0> Customer.where("customer_expiry_date <= ?",Date.today + 1.month)
  Customer Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"  WHERE (customer_expiry_date <= '2016-03-03')
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "customer_expiry_date" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "customers".* FROM "customers"  WHERE (customer_expiry_date <= '201...
                                                  ^